# File upload: create directory if it doesnt exist

Tags: angularjs, node.js, formidable

I´m handling file uploads in NodeJS with formidable. This works for me. Now I want to structure the uploads a little more. I´m passing a field from angular with my uploads, which is a `project_id`. I want to create a folder in my uploads, named by this ID and write the files in it.

So I check if the directory exists, if not I create it with `fs.mkdir` and then write the files to it. Trying this, I get a `EINVAL, rename` error and a HTTP 500 status code.

This is my attempt, anybody got an idea how to fix this?

```
 app.post('/uploads/', function(req, res, next){
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.keepExtensions = true;
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
            if (err) next (err);
            fs.exists('uploads/' + fields.project_id + '/', function (exists){
                if (exists) {
                    fs.rename(files.upload.path, 'uploads/' + fields.project_id + '/' +files.upload.name, function(err){
                        if (err) next (err);
                        res.render('profile.ejs',{
                            user: req.user
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    fs.mkdir('uploads/' + fields.project_id + '/', function (err){
                        if (err) next (err);
                    });
                    fs.rename(files.upload.path, 'uploads/' + fields.project_id + '/' + files.upload.name, function(err){
                        if(err) next (err);
                        res.render('profile.ejs',{
                            user:req.user
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to rename the file before the directory was created. Also, using [`fs.exists`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) is not advisable, and the function will be deprecated in the future.

I made some changes in your code, you could use the `path` module to create the paths. Also, try creating the directory regardless if it already exists. If it exists, ignore the error code EEXIST.

The updated code:

```
// add this to the beggining
var path = require('path');

app.post('/uploads', function(req, res, next){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
        if (err) next (err);
        fs.mkdir(path.resolve('uploads', fields.project_id), function (err) {
            if (err && err !== 'EEXIST') {
                next(err);
            } else {
                fs.rename(files.upload.path, path.resolve('uploads', fields.project_id, files.upload.name), function(err){
                    if(err) next (err);
                    res.render('profile.ejs',{
                        user:req.user
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. but still getting the same error

Comment: what's the output when you `console.log(files.upload.path)` and `console.log('uploads/' + fields.project_id + '/' + files.upload.name)`?

Comment: console.log(files.upload.path) = c:\users\david\appdata\local\temp\upload_longnumberwhichisnottheid.jpg , second log: uploads/55379andsoon/filename.jpg. The check if the directory exists doesnt seem to work, because the directory is not created and node doesnt go to the else loop.

Comment: Fixed it, problem was that i already had files in the upload folder having the project_id as filename. After deleting this files and retrying it, the directory has been created. It works! Thanks a lot Victor!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Anyway, I updated my answer with some suggestions, if you want.