# Load directory of images in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I´m trying to implement an image gallery in my Angular app. I´ve managed the upload of pictures in this post: [File upload: create directory if it doesnt exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150646/file-upload-create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist).
So files are put in a subdirectory on the basis of its `project_id`. This works fine.
So now I´d like to display the whole set of images of a project. How am I accessing the subdirectory basing on the `project_id`and how do I display a set of images in a convenient way? Any ideas are appreciated.

My try to route to the subdirectory. The GET request looks ok, the project_id is sent to the route. I can access the directory with a HTTP 200 code, but displaying the images wont work, getting a 404.

```
app.get('/uploads/:id', function (req, res, next){
    fs.readdir('uploads/'+req.params.id+'/', function (err, files){
        if (err) return next (err);
        res.send(files);
    });
});
```

**Angular Controller**

```
$http.get('/profile/project/').then(function (res){
    $scope.projects = res.data;
    $rootScope.projectId = $scope.projects._id;
    console.log($scope.projectId);
    var id = $rootScope.projectId;
    console.log("Rausgezogene ID: " + id);
    $http.get('/uploads/'+id).success(function (files){
        $scope.img = files;
    });
});
```

**Displaying**

```
<li ng-repeat="x in img">
    <img ng-src="uploads/{{projects._id}}/{{x}}" width="150" height="100"/>
</li>
```

**Console log**

[image: Console Log]

Cheers, Wandkleister.

Comment: What specific part are you having problems with? Question is a bit too broad. Do you have routing injected in app? What are display expectations?

Comment: Edited my inital post

Comment: suggest you put image assets in different directory than your api calls. Path to api route is identical to what images are

Comment: But thats the correct directory incl the right file names

Comment: right but you have an api route pointing right at it too and that route doesn't have another segment to it so it fails in the api route when all you want is images. Assets and api shouldn't have similar paths

Comment: Ok to sum it up. My API gives me all the file names in the expected directory. I scope this within angular with 'img' and repeat that in x. So my img source is /uploads/projects_id/filename.extension ... thats my understanding of the process - where am I wrong on this?

Comment: you can't have a data route pointed at the images directory! You could but that is just bad design and would need a bunch of garbage code to make it work

Comment: Sorry I´m pretty new to this. Could you give me an example of the right way to do it?

Comment: yes, separate asset and api paths ...quite simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically confusing your backend.
You need to put the images somewhere else that doesn't have a REST endpoint.  When you make the request to get the image so you can display it, your API doesn't know that.  It thinks you are trying to access a REST endpoint.

Put images somewhere, like `/public/images` if you are using a public folder, or something like that, where there is not an endpoint configured for it - just a regular folder, but publicly accessible.

OR you can keep it in uploads and change your api endpoint to something else.  Just have it return the same directory listing.

For example:
`$http.get('/getUploadsDir/someID')` - returns the file list for `/uploads/someID`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! But I´m just as confused as my backend is. I´d like to access the directory via REST. And I´m getting the right filenames and the right directory. So in my eyes it works, but there is still a 404 error. Sorry for my dumbness, don´t want to annoy you

Comment: You have your assets (images) stored in the `/uploads/` directory in subfolders with a designated id.  You have real file structure there.  But in your backend configuration you have a REST endpoint setup which has the same path as your asset directory:
`app.get('/uploads/:id'...`.  So when you try to access your images by the path in the file system, it's getting caught by your REST API.  Your API doesn't have anything defined for `/uploads/someId/someImage.jpeg`, and so it returns 404.

Comment: So when your HTML when you have `<img ng-src="uploads/{{projects._id}}/{{x}}" width="150" height="100"/>` your HTML is actually making a get request (just like angular) and it is hitting the same `app.get('/uploads/:id'...` endpoint in your API.

Comment: That made it clear for me, thank you. So how do I access my local the short way? Having the file names and the Id-directory should be enough. I´ve already changed the API endpoint to 'app.get("/getpics/:id,..', but that doesnt change that ng-src wants to look my files up in 'http://localhost:1000/uploads/someID/filename.jpg'

Comment: You want it to look up files the same way. Just change the endpoint in your API, which you said you did, and change $http.get('/uploads') in angular to $http.get('/get pics/'+id).

Comment: And if it's still 404, you need to check your backend and make sure that your uploads directory is publicly exposed.

Comment: Did that, still 404. Thats whats confusing me. How do I expose the directory publicly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78113/discussion-between-wandkleister-and-tpie).

Comment: Something like this - app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));  if the uploads folder is in your app root.