# Can I read a local folder in my system drive through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a chrome app using angularJS wherein i am maintaining students' books in a library shelf.
My requirement is to read books (with their details) from a local folder (can be a shared folder via network) in javascript.
So that if I put someone's localhost IP address of their folder into my app, my app connects to his system and fetches data from it.

Can this by any chance be achieved by web sockets?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150646/file-upload-create-directory-if-it-doesnt-exist check this answer

Comment: You could use NodeJS on the server side to accomplish this, but you will be unsuccessful if you try to use the client. Both systems would need to have a version of your custom server installed and running.

Comment: This would require some script to run outside of the browser on the client's laptop / computer. You could achieve this either with some standalone application, or with a Chrome plugin.

Comment: use a file input and FileReader() to allow the user to input local/mapped files

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. From what I read, JS doesn't allow this directly for security reasons.